# Algorithm sorting details, but without excluding

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

I have come across a problem.
I’m not asking for help how to construct what I’m searching for, but only to guide me to what I’m looking for! 
The thing I want to create is some sort of **‘Sorting Algorithm/Mechanism’**.

**Example:**
Imagine I have a database with over 1000 pictures of different vehicles.
A person sees a vehicle, he now tries to get as much information and details about that vehicle, such as:

- Shape
- number of wheels
- number and shape of windows
- number and shape of light(s)
- number and shape of exhaust(s)

Etc…

He then gives me all information about that vehicle he saw. **BUT!** Without telling me anything about:
Make and model.
…
I will now take that information and tell my database to sort out every vehicle so that it arranges all 1000 vehicle by best match, based by the description it have been given.
**But it should NOT exclude any vehicle!**

*So…*

If the person tells me that the vehicle only has 4 wheels, but in reality it has 5 (he might not have seen the fifth wheel) it should just get a bad score in the # of wheels.
But if every other aspect matches that vehicle perfect it will still get a high score.

That way we don’t exclude the vehicle that he has seen, and we still have a change to find the correct vehicle.

The whole aspect of this mechanism is to, as said, sort out the most, so instead of looking through 1000 vehicles we only need to sort through the best matches which is 10 to maybe 50 vehicles out of a 1000 (hopefully).

I tried to describe it the best I could in a language that isn’t ‘my father’s tongue’. So bear with me.

Again, I’m not looking for anybody telling me how to make this algorithm, I’m pretty sure nobody even wants of have the time to do that for me, without getting paid somehow...
But I just need to know where to look regarding learning and understanding how to create this mess of a mechanism.

*Kind regards
Gent!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your pictures have been indexed with the relevant fields (number of wheels, window shapes...), and given that they are not too numerous (a thousand is peanuts for a computer), you can proceed as follows:

- for every criterion, weight the possible discrepancies (e.g. one wheel too much costs 5, one wheel too few costs 10, bad window shape costs 8...). Make this in a coherent way so that the costs of the criteria are well balanced.
- to perform a search, evaluate the total discrepancy cost of *every car*, and sort the values increasingly. Report the first ten.

---

Technically, what you are after is called a "nearest neighbor search" in a high dimensional space. This problem has been well studied. There are fast solutions but they are extremely complex, and in your case are absolutely not worth using.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! 

Yeah, the pictures are to be indexed in different values beforehand into the smallest details.

Just looked it up, and a nearest neighbor algorithm seems like the thing I will have to look up! :)

It seems too complex for what I have described, but what I have described Isn't exactly what I'm doing tho. But something like that.

Thanks again, very much for the good answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

The default way of doing this for example in artificial intelligence is to encode all properties as a vector and applying certain weights to each property. The distance can then be calculated using any metric you like. In your case manhatten-distance should be fine. So in pseudocode:

```
distance(first_car, second_car):
    return abs(first_car.n_wheels - second_car.n_wheels) * wheels_weight+ ... + 
           abs(first_car.n_windows - second_car.n_windows) * windows_weight
```

This works fine for simple properties like the number of wheels. For more complex properties like the shape of a window you'll probably need to split it up into multiple attributes depending on your requirements on similarity.

Weights are usually picked in such a way as to normalize all values, if their range is known. Optionally an additional factor can be multiplied to increase the impact of a specific attribute on the overall distance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It is much appriciated! :)